# Need help with this proof, theory of finite change.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, normed-spaces

Theory: If $f : [a,b] \to X $ is differentiable on (a,b) and continuous on [a,b] in $X$, a normed vector space upon $ \langle , \rangle$ then:

$$|f(b)-f(a)| \leq \sup_{a <c<b}{\|f'(c)\|}(b-a)$$

Proof: (I will highlight what is unclear to me , and comment at the end what I think)

$$h_0 \in X, \ \ \  \|h_0\|=1, \ \ \ g(x)= \langle f(x), h_0 \rangle \ \ \  \text{(helping functions I believe)} \\ g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R} ;\\ x \mapsto f(x) \mapsto \langle f(x), h_0\rangle \text{ So , this function is differentiable as a composition of such)}\\ 
 \|g(b)-g(a)\|=\langle f(a)-f(b), h_0\rangle =^{\text{mean value theorem}}{|g'(c) (b-a)|= \\ \ \ \  = | \langle gradf(c), h_0 \rangle|(b-a) \leq\|gradf(c)\|\|b-a\|  }  $$

> $$(1) \ \ \ \|\langle f(a)-f(b), h_0\rangle \|= \|gradf(c)\|\|b-a\| \leq \sup{f'(c)}\|b-a\|  \\ 
>  (2) \ \ \ h_0= \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{\|f(b)-f(a)\|} \implies \|f(b)-f(a)\|\leq M (b-a)$$

For $(1)$ it seems to me the reason the inequality holds is that the left side is $\leq 0$ and on the right , because of norms $\geq 0. (2)$ is a mystery to me and the last step which I cannot understand the whole proof without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, (1) is wrong as you stated it. The key inequality is simply
$$
\|\nabla f(c)\| \leq \sup \|\nabla f\|.
$$
(2) is rather trivial: with the choice of $h_0$ you get
$$
\langle f(b)-f(a),h_0 \rangle = \frac{\|f(b)-f(a)\|^2}{\|f(b)-f(a)\|} = \|f(b)-f(a)\|.
$$
Finally, let me remark that $X$ looks like an inner product space rather than a general normed space.

Comment: I still dont see (2), (I get that I can choose this $h$) but I still cant see how the scalar product is equal to this, and how from that the theorem is concluded.

Comment: For any vector $u$, $\langle u,u \rangle = \|u\|^2$. The theorem follows setting $M=\sup \|\nabla f\|$.

Comment: Then, doesn't from $(1)$ imply: $\|f(b)-f(a)\| \leq \| gradf(c)\| \|b-a\| + \sup \|f'(c)\| \|b-a\| > \sup f'(c) \| b-a\|$

Comment: In my opinion, (1) is false. Period.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Everything is clear.